Enforce return type of method referenced by its name
I have a function that takes as parameters a method name as a string and the object that contains that method. I can easily check that the class of the object contains the method name. But I also want to make sure that it is callable and the return type is of a certain type. How can I do that?

type expected = {
    a: string;
}

function handle<T>(method: keyof T, handler : T ) {
    const f = handler[method];
    return f(); // this does not compile
}


class Handler {
    foo() {
        return 'bar';
    }
    baz() {
        return { a : 'bar'}
    }
}

handle('foo', new Handler()); // compile error - not the expected return type
handle('baz', new Handler()); // should compile


You can solve this by using constrained generic type parameters. Given the type Expected…
type Expected = { a: string };

…you can create an additional generic type parameter K for the key (method name) and constrain it by string. Then constrain T by "a type that has a property at K whose value is a 0-arity function that returns the type Expected". You can annotate this in a concise way using the type utility Record<Keys, Type> like this: Record<K, () => Expected>. Finally, annotate the return type of the function using the type Expected. All together, the description above looks like this:
TS Playground
type Expected = { a: string };

function handle<
  K extends PropertyKey,
  T extends Record<K, () => Expected>,
>(method: K, handler: T): Expected {
  const f = handler[method];
  return f();
}

class Handler {
  foo() {
    return "bar";
  }
  baz() {
    return { a: "bar" };
  }
}

handle("foo", new Handler()); /* Error
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Argument of type 'Handler' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<"foo", () => Expected>'.
  The types returned by 'foo()' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Expected'.(2345) */

handle("baz", new Handler()); // Ok



first use type guards and generics.
Define the expected return type you want.
Use type assertions and type guards to check the method and its return type.
You can use the snippet bellow:
type Expected = {
    a: string;
};

function handle<T, K extends keyof T>(method: K, handler: T): Expected {
    const f = handler[method];

    if (typeof f === 'function') {
        const result = (f as Function).call(handler);

        // Check if result is of the expected type
        if (isExpected(result)) {
            return result;
        } else {
            throw new Error(`The return type of ${String(method)} is not as expected.`);
        }
    } else {
        throw new Error(`${String(method)} is not a function.`);
    }
}

// Type guard to check if the result is of type Expected
function isExpected(result: any): result is Expected {
    return result && typeof result === 'object' && 'a' in result && typeof result.a === 'string';
}

class Handler {
    foo() {
        return 'bar';
    }
    baz() {
        return { a: 'bar' };
    }
}

try {
    console.log(handle('baz', new Handler())); // should compile and run
    console.log(handle('foo', new Handler())); // should throw an error
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}




